# Cannot use core TCL package csv

Tags: tcl

I cannot use a core package (http://wiki.tcl.tk/38945)

Here is my code:

```
puts $auto_path

package require csv

puts "required package csv"
```

And here is the output:

```
tclsh createcvs.tcl 
/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6 /usr/share/tcltk /usr/lib /usr/local/lib/tcltk /usr/local/share/tcltk /usr/lib/tcltk/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/tcltk /usr/lib/tcltk/tcl8.6
can't find package csv
    while executing
"package required"
    (file "createcvs.tcl" line 4)
```

I am using the default installation of tcl in my ubuntu 15.10

Is there a way to check if this package is available in my machine?

Thanks

Comment: Your code didn't make it into your question text. Is it **cvs** or **csv** you want to use? You should be able to get `csv` by using the command `teacup install csv`. If you get a "can't find package" message, then the package isn't currently available on your machine.

Comment: @ Peter, I do not have teacup in my computer. I am using the default installation of tcl in my ubuntu 15.10. What is the best way to proceed now? uninstall tcl and install activetcl from downloaded file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tcl on Ubuntu, and my son (who is) isn't around. All I can say is that ActiveTcl works well for me on Windows; I use the `csv` package every day.

Comment: I've corrected the title but you've not pasted the shortest code that reproduces your output. I'm guessing it is something like `puts $auto_path;package require csv`…

Comment: @Donal, thank you for pointing that out. Copy/paste error. my bad!I am gonna correct this right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go install the [tcllib](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tcllib&searchon=names) package: `sudo apt-get install tcllib`

Comment: this makes more sense and it works for me. Thank you glenn!